# facebook_scraper.exceptions.LoginRequired: A login (cookies) is required to see this page

Tags: python

```
from facebook_scraper import get_group_info

cookie = '?'

print(get_group_info('lebanon', cookie=cookie))
```

> I am trying to scrape facebook groups but it telling me that 'facebook_scraper.exceptions.LoginRequired: A login (cookies) is required to see this page', how do I get this cookie...?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem recently and it was actually quite easy to fix. All you need to do is add the cookies parameter to the function (for example get_group_info or get_posts).

The [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/facebook-scraper/) states that you need to include:

> The path to a file containing cookies in Netscape or JSON format. You can extract cookies from your browser after logging into Facebook with an extension like Get Cookies.txt (Chrome) or Cookie Quick Manager (Firefox). Make sure that you include both the c_user cookie and the xs cookie, you will get an InvalidCookies exception if you don't.

So, simply add the extension based on which browser you use, visit Facebook and log in, and then use the extension to extract and save your cookies in Netscape format. Save the file somewhere and then just read it into your code, for example:

```
get_group_info("nintendo", cookies="/path/to/cookies/file")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's required to add your credentials (username and password)

```
for post in get_posts(group=group_name, pages=1, credentials=(email , password)):
  print(post)
```

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of Paige's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous solution would like to mention a variation using the cookies directly from the browser without having to export the cookies file using **browser_cookie3**
https://pypi.org/project/browser-cookie3/, e.g. loading Chrome's Facebook cookies:

```
cj = browser_cookie3.chrome(domain_name='.facebook.com')
posts = get_posts(group=group_id, cookies=cj)
```

Answer (score -1):

the solution is actually super simple, you just need to type in your like this:

```
for post in get_posts(group='EatsleeprepeatESR/', credentials={'email' : '6969@gmail.com' , 'pass' : '*****************'}):
    print(post['text'][:50])
```